# How to serialize and deserialize MyClass with JSON serializer?

Tags: .net, json, windows-phone-8.1, serialization

Hello I am having trouble implementing this code into Visual Basic for Window phone using my own class structure. I want to be able to save instances of my objects and retrieve them from a file. Once I figure out the writing, the reading should be identical. I got this code from this tutorial:  [Serialize Tutorial](http://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Phone-8-1-Development-for-Absolute-Beginners/Part-22-Storing-and-Retrieving-Serialized-Data)

```
private const string JSONFILENAME = "data.json";

private async Task writeJsonAsync()
{
  // Notice that the write is ALMOST identical ... except for the serializer.

  var myCars = buildObjectGraph();

  var serializer = new DataContractJsonSerializer(typeof(List<Car>));
  using (var stream = await ApplicationData.Current.LocalFolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(
                JSONFILENAME,
                CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting))
  {
  serializer.WriteObject(stream, myCars);
  }

  resultTextBlock.Text = "Write succeeded";
}
```

My class structure is something like this

```
MyClass1 inherits MyClass2
MyClass2 inherits MyClass3
MyClass4
```

This is how far I've gotten

```
Dim test as MyClass4 = new MyClass4
Dim serializer as New DataContractJsonSeializer(MyClass4)
Dim stream as System.IO.Stream = Await ApplicationData.Current.localfolder.OpenStreamForWriteAsync(dir,CreationCollisionOption.ReplaceExisting)
```

The problem is I can't initialize the serializer because `MyClass4` is a Type and cannot be used as an expression. But the parameter is asking for System.Type I am confused. Please help.

```
Dim serializer as New DataContractJsonSeializer(MyClass4) //gives me an error here
```

Comment: I am not a VB guy, but this may solve your problem 
`Dim serializer = New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(MyClass4))` .

Comment: Thanks that worked.

Comment: @Zocoloni: consider accepting his answer as it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a VB guy, but this may solve your problem

```
Dim serializer = New DataContractJsonSerializer(GetType(MyClass4));
```